# Using `instanceof` on objects created with constructors from deep npm dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

### Background:

I have an npm module that I have common error handling code in, including a custom error:

```
function CustomError () { /* ... */ }
CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
CustomError.prototype.constructor = CustomError;
module.exports = CustomError;
```

I have some other modules (let's call them **'module-a'** and **'module-b'**) which both depend on the error handling module.

I also have some code with uses Bluebirds "filtered catch" functionality:

```
doSomething
.catch(CustomError, () => { /* ... */ });
```

### The issue:

After some debugging I've discovered (somewhat obviously in hindsight) that errors created in **'module-a'** are not instances of errors created by **'module-b'**. This is because both modules have their own copy of the JS file containing the `CustomError` constructor, which are both run independently.

I would rather not have to resort to my current solution, which is basically:

```
CustomError.isCustomError = e => e.constructor.toString() === CustomError.toString();
```

and then:

```
doSomething
.then(CustomError.isCustomError, () => { /* ... */ });
```

This is clearly flimsy, and will fall apart if the versions fall out of sync.

### So...

Is there some way to ensure that **'module-a'** and **'module-b'** both use the same instance of the constructor? Or another, less fragile solution.

Answer (score 14):

This is actually a problem in browsers too, when you have an iframe it gets its own copy of, for example, the Array constructor (making `instanceof` useless).

The solution for a custom constructor is to duck-type it. Here are some potential solutions with pros and cons.

1. Check the constructor name. Pro: simple, well-supported. Con: better pick a fairly unique name to avoid false positives and forget about sub-classing it.
2. Check the properties of the object (e.g. has both 'foo' and 'bar and 'foo' is a function). Pro: mostly fool-proof. Cons: fragile: this check may randomly break if you refactor your custom error class, relatively expensive.
3. (Recommended) Add a property/method. This is how a number of libraries (for example, moment.js) handle this problem.

Code example:

```
CustomError.prototype._isCustomError = true;
var isCustomError = function isCustomError(obj) {
  return obj instanceof CustomError || Boolean(obj._isCustomError);
};

module.exports = {
  CustomError,
  isCustomError
};
```

This is more or less exactly how moment detects whether or not a given object is a moment object.

Comment: Yeah, nice, that's basically what I've done now, seems reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: So I've been thinking and another (quite nice) way to do this is to override `Symbol.hasInstance`, but support for that is a bit lacking currently.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal yup. This is pretty much the exact use case for that. Someday we'll get there....

Answer (score -2):

What do you mean by:

> After some debugging I've discovered (somewhat obviously in hindsight)
>   that errors created in 'module-a' are not instances of errors created
>   by 'module-b'.

Error object can't be instance of another error object. Or you are saying that errors from `module-a` or `module-b` when doing something like `err instanceof CustomError` are returning different results? Having in mind that `instanceof` tests presence of `constructor.prototype` in object's prototype chain both errors from those modules should return `true` by code that you posted, when tested againt `CustomError`.

**Can you show how you are creating those errors in those modules?**

> This is because both modules have their own copy of the JS file
>   containing the CustomError constructor, which are both run
>   independently.

Again, im confused by this statement. What do you mean by both modules have their own copy of something? Lets have small example:

```
// custom-error.js
'use strict'

function CustomError () {}

CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype)
CustomError.prototype.constructor = CustomError

module.exports = CustomError

// module-a.js
const CustomError = require('./custom-error')
const err = new CustomError(...)
module.exports = err

// module-b.js
const CustomError = require('./custom-error')
const err = new CustomError(...)
module.exports = err

// dummy file to require those
const CustomError = require('./custom-error')
const errA = require('./module-a')
const errB = require('./module-b')
```

First both `errA` and `errB` should be an `instanceof CustomError`:

```
console.log(errA instanceof CustomError) // yields true
console.log(errB instanceof CustomError) // yields true
```

`cunstructor` property of `errA` and `errB` that will be found in prototype chain, should have reference that points to same function object `CustomError`

```
console.log(errA.constructor === errB.constructor) // yields true
```

Lets introduce also filtered catch example:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
  throw errA
})
.catch(CustomError, err => {
  console.log('instance of CustomError catched', err)
  throw errB
})
.catch(CustomError, err => {
  console.log('instance of CustomError catched again', err)
})
```

Results:

```
instance of CustomError catched [Error]
instance of CustomError catched again [Error]
```

And last thing, what do you mean in your example when you say `deep npm dependencies`? This `CustomError` thing is your module or 3rd party lib? The fact that is 3rd party module or not, that should not change anything.

Comment: The bit that you're missing is that they are *published* modules. So instead of `const CustomError = require('./custom-error')` it's really `const CustomError = require('custom-error')`. This is how they get two copies of the actual source, which run independently creating two different constructors.