# instanceof not work correctly in typescript library project

Tags: typescript, shared-libraries, nestjs

I build a typescript library project. and use some classes from a public package.
let's say a simple function to test it is a BadRequestException or not

```
import { BadRequestException } from "@nestjs/common";
export function test(error) {
  let a = error;
  let b = BadRequestException;
  console.log(a instanceof b);
}
```

after build and import this `shared-lib` library from another normal project
and i called like this

```
import { BadRequestException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { test } from 'shared-lib';
test(new BadRequestException('it is a test error'));
```

in my throught(it should be), `a instance b` in test function should be equals `true`,however,i got `false`

[image]

is that `BadRequestException` used in the library project is different from that in the second project, even both of them are imported from `"@nestjs/common"`?

**uploaded a [demo project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265098/instanceof-not-work-correctly-in-typescript-library-project) in Github**

Comment: This issue could be related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22585

Answer (score 5):

instanceof checks if the constructors are the same. The thing is that your code gets its own copy of the constructor from the code in the library (because that's how it is, it's not your fault), so they are not the same instance anymore.

The constructors still share the same name though:

```
error.constructor.name === BadRequestException.prototype.constructor.name
```

[See related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592087/5811234)

Comment: just to simplify: `BadRequestException.prototype.constructor === BadRequestException`

Answer (score 1):

Using the accepted answer, you can create a narrowing function using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

E.g.:

```
const isBadRequestException = (error: any): error is BadRequestException => {
  return error.constructor.name === BadRequestException.prototype.constructor.name;
}
```

Then you can use this for subsequent typed access to the error object:

```
if (isBadRequestException(error)) {
  error... // Properties now available
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so, you cannot declare a variable as a class prototype and use instanceof because the variable has not been instanced. In other words, b is essentially `Object {}`. This work work however

```js
export const test = error => error instanceof BadRequestException;
```

But Classes in JS are quite weird. Technically all 'classes' are objects `Object {}` so their 'parent' prototype, as I understand it will be Object and the overwrite will be `BadRequestException`.

If you're handling your classes weirdly, it might be better to use prototypeof but I wouldn't recommend this

```js
export const test = error => Reflect.getPrototypeOf(error) === BadRequestException;
```

Comment: even I tried your solution, it still gets FALSE. I think the problem maybe typescript treat 'BadRequestException' in these 2 project's node_modules are different things, even through they are in the same "@nestjs/common" package

Comment: it's more than likely that your constant `error` is no longer an instance of `BadRequestException`. Using spreads will result in the variable becoming an instance of object and no `BadRequestException`

Comment: well, not working... still get FALSE. I uploaded a demo project into GITHUB. plz have a look if not taken too much of your time.  https://github.com/minzojian/instanceofcheck.git

Comment: your example works for me X'D https://github.com/minzojian/instanceofcheck/pull/1

Comment: test instanceof in the same project is meanless. my issue is, the same Class that defined in lib-proj is not the same with that in app-proj. even though they both are BadRequestException and imported from same '@nestjs/common' package